# How do I paste long arguments into the debugger in Windows? 

Tags: windows, haskell, cmd, ghci

I'm trying to write my function's arguments in a text editor and paste them into the console, but the console won't let me.
(My list of arguments is long and the formatting starts to go crazy.)

I'm using ghci running in a `cmd.exe` window.

What can I do?

Comment: Why can't you paste into the console? (Are you using windows?)

Comment: Yeh, when i right-click it doesnt do anything, nor does ctrl+v

Comment: [Does this work?](http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_paste_into_a_windows_xp_command_shell.html)

Comment: (Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210245/can-i-get-copy-paste-functionality-from-a-c-sharp-console-window)?)

Comment: Put as answer- me accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, in a windows console you can right-click the title bar and do `Edit  >  Paste`.

If you'd rather just right-click in the window to paste immediately, you can turn on `QuickEdit` Mode:

- Right-click the title bar of the window, and choose `Properties`.
- Select the `Options` tab
- In `Edit Options`, tick `QuickEdit Mode`
- Click OK, and when it asks you, choose
- Save properties for future windows with the same title. This means it'll happen every time you run ghci.

Works under XP, and as far as I can tell via Google, the same trick works in Vista and Windows 7.

This also has the effect that you don't need to choose `Edit > Mark` to select text. (Press enter after selecting to copy, and of course, right-click to paste.)