# How to programmatically select text in a console application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console-application

I can't seem to find how to select text in my console application via WinAPI. Pretty much what could be done with the mouse, if someone right-clicks the console window and selects "Mark":

[image]

and then drags the mouse on the console window:

[image]

Can I do this with WinAPIs?

Comment: Here is how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210245/can-i-get-copy-paste-functionality-from-a-c-sharp-console-window

Comment: @Nope, The question is to do it programmatically.

Comment: [`ReadConsoleOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684965(v=vs.85).aspx) looks like it should do.

Comment: @chris: That's the read it. But how do I select it?

Comment: I doubt there is an official way to do that programmatically. It sounds very sketchy that the intent would not be to copy that text. It can, of course, be done by pretending you're the user, but that comes with many drawbacks.

Comment: There's [GetConsoleSelectionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683173(v=vs.85).aspx) that supposedly can tell you what is selected, but then there's no SetConsoleSelection to select anything. As for not allowing it "officially" I don't see the reason why? It's already on the screen, so why not allow it...

Comment: @chris: Also how come one can put a console into "quick edit mode" with `ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` flag and `SetConsoleMode` call but then not be able to select anything?

Comment: @c00000fd: because `ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` is meant to allow the **user** to use the mouse to select text, just as the documentation says. What benefit is there for the **application** to select text?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well, if it was OS X I'd say, "no, we do what Steve told us to do." But this is Windows. Apps do whatever the heck they want :) Plus one can never predict an application for some feature. So limiting it has no practical benefit, especially when it doesn't contradict security. But I know, it's just rhetoric...

Comment: Windows was not designed for apps to "do whatever the heck they want" either. It was actually designed with the erroneous assumption that apps would always do the right thing. The designers have since had to backpedal, writing code to prevent apps from doing the wrong thing. It is quite unclear from your question why you would ever want to select text in a console window *programmatically*. What would be the next step? Copy the text? There are already good ways of doing that without having to manipulate the console and inject mouse events. This is just a bad idea, whether you're Bill or Steve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to do what you are asking for.  So you will have to simulate it instead.

Use `SetConsoleMode()` to enable the `ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` to enable selecting text with the mouse.  Then use `SendInput()` or `mouse_event()` to manipulate mouse movement and clicks as needed.

Use `GetConsoleWindow()` to get the console's `HWND`, and `GetWindowRect()` to get its position onscreen.  Use `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo/Ex()` to get the column/row counts of the console, and the rectangle where the characters appear within the console window.  Then you should be able to use some math to translate character column/row offsets into screen coordinates as needed when sending mouse actions.

Comment: Well, that's one way. Just curious, since console [can process mouse events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035(v=vs.85).aspx), is there a way to simulate those instead of sending generic mouse input?

Comment: @c00000fd: AFAIK, the console API can only *process* mouse events, it cannot *generate* them.  Thus the need to go higher up the API chain outside of the console. Though you *might* be able to get away with posting `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP)` messages directly to the console window.  Or use UIAutomation to simulate mouse input on the console window.

Comment: I'll mark it as a solution "of sorts." Sending direct input to the console via `SendInput` works, but is very clumsy and unreliable (i.e. it depends on the console window to have keyboard focus at the time when `SendInput` is called.)

Answer (score 0):

Use ReadConsoleOutput to read the area that you want to select. Change the received CHAR_INFO Attributes for each character to reflect different (e.g. inverted) colours. Use WriteConsoleOutput to write the modified data to the same rectangular area. This will show a 'selected' area. If needed use SetConsoleCursorPosition to change the cursor position. An example how to use the ReadConsoleOutput and WriteConsoleOutput can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685032(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yeah. That's just for highlighting. I'm asking about emulation of selection that is usually done with the mouse after a console is put in `ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` with `SetConsoleMode`.