# Why the content in the Tectia and Git Console can't be selected?

Tags: git, console

Why after selecting content in the console, it will jump to the new line (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> have been pressed) after the mouse is released?

[image: git console]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2210624/7976758

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/435958

Answer (score 0):

Go to top of the terminal or command line and right click and try mark,
and select the text you wanted to copy and it will automatically copy to clipboard

[image]

Comment: thx~, but my other colleagues didn't meet such issue, I guess it should be some configure but don't know where it is

Comment: i guess this is already existing issues checkout the two comments to you post, that has solution clearly explained well

Comment: thx, that walk around works, but in other one PC, there not such issue...